# What is the Corresponding Operation of Möbius Addition for Spherical Geometries?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry

In hyperbolic geometry one can use the Möbius addition
$$
x\oplus_K y
:=
\frac{
(1-2K\langle x,y \rangle-K||y||_2^2)x
+
(1+K||x||_2^2) y
}{
1-2K\langle x,y\rangle +K^2||x||_2^2||y||_2^2
}
$$
for elements $x,y$ on the Poincaré disk of sectional curvature $K<0$.

Note that for $K=0$ one just recovers the Euclidean vector space addition.

This allows to perform additions as follows:

[image]

Is there some corresponding addition that is defined for the *stereographic* projection of the sphere? Can one maybe just use the $\oplus_K$ of above with $K>0$?

Comment: Where did you get the definition of the Möbius addition from? Does the same source say anything about spherical spaces or does it only mention hyperbolic spaces? According to this page, which was written a few months after your question, the formula should work for all $K$ (that is, for both hyperbolic spaces, the Euclidean space and spherical spaces): https://andbloch.github.io/K-Stereographic-Model/#ungar2005analytic