# Vector Addition/Translation in Hyperboloid model

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions, noneuclidean-geometry

I have problems understanding vector addition in Hyperbolic space. In the Poincaré ball model, vector addition/translation is the Möbis addition and defined as:

$$ x \oplus_c y = \frac{(1+2c\langle x,y \rangle+c \lVert y \rVert^2)x+(1-c \lVert x \rVert^2)y}{1+2c \langle x,y \rangle+c^2 \lVert x \rVert^2 \lVert y \rVert^2}$$

with c being the curvature. I was wondering how a vector addition/translation is defined in the hyperboloid model? Unfortunately, I couldn't find an exact answer. I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!!! :D

Comment: I did not check, but, most likely, this notion is defined by identifying hyperbolic space with a vector space (the tangent space $V$ at $o$) via Riemannian exponential/logarithmic map as in my other answer. If $f: V\to {\mathbb H}^n$ is this identification, you define $x\oplus y:= f(f^{-1}(x) + f^{-1}(y))$. Why would anybody want to do this, I have no idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! But I think the Möbius addition is used in Gyrovector spaces: "In particular, these operations are used in special relativity, allowing to add speed vectors belonging to the Poincaré ball of radius c (the celerity, i.e. the speed of light) so that they remain in the ball, hence not exceeding the speed of light" - "Hyperbolic Neural Networks".

Comment: I found a thread with a similar question and a good figure: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303517/what-is-the-corresponding-operation-of-möbius-addition-for-spherical-geometries