# How to define addition law in hyperboloid model(lorentz space) of hyperbolic space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-equations, semi-riemannian-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I know  mobius addition and Einstein addition are well defined in Poincaré ball model . But how to define addition in  hyperboloid model(lorentz space) of hyperbolic space,and can we define the exact formula for this operation? I find some results from [Vector Addition/Translation in Hyperboloid model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016314/vector-addition-translation-in-hyperboloid-model), but still confused.